# I was expecting a `,` or a `}`

Tags: bibtex, errors

So I have some code which always gives a weird error, even when there is clearly not an error in the code.

The error it gives me is:

```
The style file: apalike.bst
Database file #1: Hoofdstukken/Bibliografie.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 58 of file Hoofdstukken/Bibliografie.bib
 : 
 : @article{boehm1988spiral,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

So in my table of contents I am referring to a `.bib` file:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Referenties}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Hoofdstukken/Bibliografie}
```

And in my `.bib` file is the following:

```
@article{balaji2012waterfall,
  title={Waterfall vs. {V}-Model vs. Agile: A comparative study on {SDLC},
  author={Balaji, S and Murugaiyan, M Sundararajan},
  journal={International Journal of Information Technology and Business Management},
  volume={2},
  number={1},
  pages={26--30},
  year={2012}
}


@article{boehm1988spiral, \\line 58 here
  title={A spiral model of software development and enhancement},
  author={Boehm, Barry W},
  journal={Computer},
  volume={21},
  number={5},
  pages={61--72},
  year={1988},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

I commented every single `@article` in my document but it does not make any difference ...

Now when I have an error in other code, it will give me the error of the `.bib` file, while the error is definitely not in the `.bib` file.

So why is it doing this? I am using the following `\documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, twoside, openright, tikz]{report}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error was detected in line 58, but its cause is before:

```
@article{balaji2012waterfall,
  title={Waterfall vs. {V}-Model vs. Agile: A comparative study on {SDLC},
```

The `title` value misses the closing curly brace at the end of the value:

```
@article{balaji2012waterfall,
  title={Waterfall vs. {V}-Model vs. Agile: A comparative study on {SDLC}},
```

Comment: wow... im so blind. This is indeed the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when writing 2 term in article.

```
@article={cabinet office,
```

its showing "`,`" or "`}`" missing. then remove the space and error gone.

```
@article={cabinetoffice,
```

is the correction in my case.